# bogus glyphs in plots - jupyter R (Ipython notebook)

Tags: r, ipython, jupyter

This problem is difficult to explain.   I am looking for suggestions on where to look or how to get further information.

Using R in Jupyter, my plots come out with bogus text labels.

[image: plot with bogus tick and axis labels]

I have figured out that the bogus labels only occur when another plot occurs earlier on the same page.   The first plot is ok, but the second plot is screwy.

[image of two simple plots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/laEwA.png)

The order of plots doesn't matter; the first one is always fine and the second is screwed up.

[image reordered simple plots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/id3Ek.png)

If I inspect the second graphical element in the simple example, I see the x-axis label is rendered like this:

```
<g style="fill:rgb(0%,0%,0%);fill-opacity:1;">
  <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#glyph0-7" x="215.398438" y="197.057617"></use>
  <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#glyph0-8" x="218.734375" y="197.057617"></use>
  <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#glyph0-9" x="225.40625" y="197.057617"></use>
  <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#glyph0-10" x="232.078125" y="197.057617"></use>
  <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#glyph0-11" x="238.450195" y="197.057617"></use>
</g>
```

It looks like somehow the definitions of "#glyph0-7" et al are getting screwed up.

The same problem also occurs if I plot using the ggplot2 package.

Does anyone have a suggestion on where to look for the cause?

```
ipython==3.1.0

> library(IRkernel)
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.1.3 (2015-03-09)
Platform: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8     LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8   
 [6] LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8    LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                  LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] IRkernel_0.3

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] base64enc_0.1-2 digest_0.6.8    evaluate_0.5.5  IRdisplay_0.3   jsonlite_0.9.14 repr_0.1.0.9000 rzmq_0.7.7      stringr_0.6.2   uuid_0.1-1
```

Comment: I think this is a known problem with SVG graphics. If so, it's already been fixed, but we need to make a new release of IRkernel. I'll try to make that happen.

Comment: Thanks, I've subscribed to the 0.4 release issue and will update as soon as it is available.